# one hot encoding for huge number of tags

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

I am puzzled with a question and would like your opinions. I am working on a convolution Neural network in tensorflow. Now I have images with tags. There are around 10000 unique tags and I would like images to be automatically tagged.
Now I use one hot encoding for labels. For 10000 unique tags it will be like feature erruption. Howcan we deal with such situations?

How do facebook do it in face tagging? There are millions of faces. I guess they do not do one hot encoding for face tag right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In face recognition, the standard way to handle millions of classes is by using an **embedding**. The CNN produces an embedding of size between 64 and 1024.

In this embedding space, each class of images should form a cluster of images, and clusters of different classes should be far apart.

---

The approach of Facebook is described in their [DeepFace paper](https://research.facebook.com/publications/deepface-closing-the-gap-to-human-level-performance-in-face-verification/) (June 2014), but I would recommend a more recent approach from Google using **triplet loss**: [FaceNet: A Unified Embedding for Face Recognition and Clustering](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832).

[image: triplet loss]

Comment: Thanks nicely explained.

Comment: Please remember to accept your favourite answer, so SO can properly retire the question.